# Is there a name for a relationship like idempotence between two functions?

Tags: functions, terminology, idempotents

If $f(f(x)) = f(x) \quad \forall \space x$ then $f$ is idempotent.

If $g(f(x)) = f(x) \quad \forall \space x$ then is there a term to describe the relationship between $g$ and $f$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't *think* there is a name for it, but the property could be stated as "$g$ is the identity on the range of $f$".

Answer (score 0):

I believe one could say that $f$ is an **equalizer** of $g$ and $id$. (Since $g \circ f = id \circ f$.)

Comment: Oh, yes, double fail - didn't read the question properly, and used the definition of coequaliser instead of equaliser.

Comment: Corrected my attempted answer.